# About to start first campaign. Question re: Treantmonk's Guide to Rangers

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e, optimization, ranger

I decided to select the Ranger class for my first campaign. I used [Treantmonk's Guide to Rangers](https://docs.google.com/Doc?docid=0AcNyxDTKvAmqZGRtZzhzdjZfNWM0cTliaGdw&hl=en) (switch hitter) for my first build. I added Beastmaster and Skirmisher to supplement my expected play style and to compliment my group composition.

My question is; In his example build he nets 2d6+9 damage from a Greatsword at first level as a human with 18(+4) Strength. I have no idea where his +9 is coming from. 2d6 base damage plus 1.5x Strength modifier = 2d6+6 damage. This is reflected in my Hero Lab character sheet. What am I missing?

> Human 15 point stat buy
>
> Str (+2 racial): 18 (10) 
>   Dex: 13 (3)
>   Con: 13 (3)
>   Wis: 13 (3)
>   Int: 10
>   Cha: 7 (-4)
>
> Raise the Dex at level 4, the Con at level 8, the Wis at level 12, and Str at levels 16 >and 20.
>
> Level 1: Feats: Power attack/Cleave: At this level the character is a Greatsword Wielder.  With a Breastplate he has a 17 AC, and 12 HP (for first level not too bad).  `His to hit with his Greatsword is +4, and damage is 2d6+9 (pretty good)`

Comment: Welcome to the site! Interesting question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Those are your stats when using the Power Attack feat.

You are correct: your normal to hit and damage would be +5/2d6+6; but if you use [Power Attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/power-attack-combat---final) with a two-handed weapon, you trade a -1 to hit for a +3 to damage. Try checking the Power Attack feat usage in Hero Lab to see a change into your attack stats.

*Note:* [pathfinder](/questions/tagged/pathfinder)'s Power Attack is better than its [dnd-3.5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-3.5e) version (which, instead, grants a -1/+2 trade off with two-handed weapons).

Comment: Ha! Of course... I don't know why I assumed he was talking about natural damage modifiers. Thanks!